# exit with error message in bash (oneline)

Tags: bash, message, exit

Is it possible to exit on error, with a message, **without** using **if** statements?

```
[[ $TRESHOLD =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || exit ERRCODE "Threshold must be an integer value!"
```

Of course the right side of `||` won't work, just to give you better idea of what I am trying to accomplish.

Actually, I don't even mind with which ERR code it's gonna exit, just to show the message.

**EDIT**

I know this will work, but how to suppress `numeric arg required` showing
after my custom message?

```
[[ $TRESHOLD =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || exit "Threshold must be an integer value!"
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

`exit` doesn't take more than one argument. To print any message like you want, you can use `echo` and then exit.

```
    [[ $TRESHOLD =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || \
     { echo "Threshold must be an integer value!"; exit $ERRCODE; }
```

Comment: Can you explain from where it was comming the message `numeric argument required`, and why I couldn't disable it with `2>/dev/null`?

Comment: Likely that `TRESHOLD` is empty. `echo` goes to stdout. So redirecting 2 will not work. You can print to stderr: `[[ $TRESHOLD =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || { echo 1>&2 "Threshold must be an integer value!"; exit $ERRCODE; }`

Comment: It's not empty, because when not provided, it has default value set. And I ment on my example `|| exit "message"`, without using `echo`

Comment: `exit` accepts only an option *integer* (exit code). So passing a string like `"message"` won't work.

Comment: Oh yes. I am stupid, I was confused because printing of my custom msg was side effect, of that error.

Answer (score 67):

You can use a helper function:

```
function fail {
    printf '%s\n' "$1" >&2 ## Send message to stderr.
    exit "${2-1}" ## Return a code specified by $2, or 1 by default.
}

[[ $TRESHOLD =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || fail "Threshold must be an integer value!"
```

Function name can be different.

Comment: You mean if I say `error_exit "msg" CODE`? I like your helper function :)

Answer (score 7):

Using `exit` directly may be tricky as the script may be sourced from other places. I prefer instead using subshell with `set -e` (plus errors should go into cerr, not cout) :

```
set -e
[[ $TRESHOLD =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || \
     (>&2 echo "Threshold must be an integer value!"; exit $ERRCODE)
```

Answer (score 1):

how about just echo a text and then exit:

```
echo "No Such File" && exit
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the last part will always run.